# "I have written a book" or "I wrote a book" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

Past perfect vs Past simple problems always baffle me..

When I want to talk about my experience of writing a book and getting a revision
on it in the past, should I use past perfect? or simple past?

> I have written a book and had someone look at it after.
>
> I wrote a book and had someone look at it after.

I want to know the difference between the two sentence or which one is correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence seems to be ungrammatical because of not considering the tense agreement. In the first part of your sentence:

> I have written a book

the tense is present perfect, but then you have used "had" which is simple past.

You will find many answers regarding the difference between present perfect and simple past, if you search the ELL.

When you say:

> I **wrote** a book.

you are actually talking about an event in the past that has finished.

When you say:

> I **have written** a book.

you are talking about a finished event that is relevant in the present situation. For example, you want to say that you have the experience of writing a book.

> He wants my advice because I **have written** a book on the subject.